# How do I clear xmodmap settings?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Exactly what the title asks. How do I clear xmodmap settings?

I have an IBM model M, and somehow xkeycaps got it into its head that my <kbd>End</kbd> key was not any key at all. `xev` reports keypresses when I use it, so I know the event is being generated by the keyboard. Also, xkeycaps thinks that my arrow keys are all wonky, and apparently the scrollbar is broken so it only scrolls down - so I can't scroll up to find an IBM keyboard that just maybe is close to my map so I can fix my keys.

So I'm trying to reset my keyboard to the default settings, but the xmodmap manpage is woefully devoid of "reset all" or "clear all" or anything of that nature (that I was able to find).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`xmodmap` has no notion of state, so it has no way to reset state directly.  You can simulate it by using `xmodmap -pke >.xmodmap.orig` before making any changes (although it doesn't save the modifier map, which you would have to save and restore manually) — but it's a bit too late for that.

Modern systems don't generally use `xmodmap` to configure the keyboard, though.  `setxkbmap` is the modern way to do it; and that *does* reset bindings when run.  So you may be able to use `setxkbmap -layout us` to reset things to normal.  More complete would be to check for the default configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  For example, on my system

```
jinx:718 Z$ sed -n '/Identifier.*Keyboard/,/EndSection/p' /etc/X11/xorg.conf
        Identifier      "Generic Keyboard"
        Driver  "kbd"
        Option  "XkbModel"      "pc105"
        Option  "XkbLayout"     "us"
        Option  "XkbOptions"    "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

The corresponding command is

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

If there were an `XkbVariant` entry in the output, you would pass its value with `-variant`.  One thing to watch out for is that options are handled specially:  you can only set one option per `-option` parameter, and you need to use `-option ''` to reset parameters first.  So to fully reset when there is something like `XkbOptions "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:ctrls_toggle"` you would need

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us -option '' -option grp:alt_shift_toggle -option grp:ctrls_toggle
```

Comment: `setxkbmap -layout us` has reset my keys, thank you!

Comment: Another very helpful option I discovered is `setxkbmap -query` to print out the current settings in xkb's format, which helped me to [configure my Apple keyboard](http://superuser.com/a/622365/162627) as desired from the terminal.

Comment: careful with that command of `setxkbmap -layout us` as it will restore the `us` layout for every language support you have. For instance my french key layout along with my english key layout turns to be qwerty insteady of azerty..

Comment: This question is about xmodmap not xkb. These applications are conflicting, and if your system does use xmodmap (as does modern Ubuntu) you may get confused after using the xkb reset command and then attempt to modify key bindings in xmodmap (as I did)

Answer (score 37):

`setxkbmap -option` resets the meta keys to default.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: just what I was looking for, and found on the man page - clears ALL mods.

Comment: This worked for me! I had at some point in time on this machine decided i wanted a regular keyboard to mirror a mac keyboard and swapped Alt and Super. What's driving me nuts is that I have to re-run `setxkbmap -option` each time i boot now, to undo my horrible idea from before... Some config I added that I need to find is forcing the modifier key swap...

Comment: @StevenLu , check `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard-layout.conf`

Comment: it's worked kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 9):

Experimenting with `xmodmap`, I messed up my key settings by using
 `xmodmap -en "keysym BackSpace = Delete"`.   Thought the `-n` flag would cause no action to be taken because the `man xmodmap` page stated that

```
-n      This  option indicates that xmodmap should not change the mappings, but should display what it would
               do, like make(1) does when given this option.
```

However, the command caused my `Delete` key to be useless.

After reading the above, I just typed `setxkbmap`, hoping it would show me the options, whereas in fact it returned immediately with no output, and then my `Delete` key was miraculously working again!

So it looks as though

```
setxkbmap
```

alone will do the job...

Comment: simple & perfectly worked! :)

Comment: Yeah this is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

I execute `xmodmap` commands via terminal.

After restarting GNOME(`ALT+f2` `r` `Enter`) it reverts back. Kind of workaround but works.

Also this is better option.

- https://superuser.com/a/1483559/507962

Answer (score 0):

xmodmap will reset upon plugging in a new keyboard.

Thus, unplug and plug in a keyboard (in either order)

That will reset xmodmap.