# Keyboard layout indicator "work" but the keyboard layout doesn't actually switch

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, 14.04, keyboard-layout, xfce

In Xfce, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard indicator switch between us and ru but the layout doesn't switch actually.

Xubuntu 14.04

I've tried: different keyboards (doesn't help).

This problem appeared after I remapped a certain key following this: [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

Update. The problem affects KDE desktop environment too. In Unity everything is OK.

Comment: I have the same problem here..

Answer (score 2):

When I had Xubuntu I had the same issue just for Hebrew. But playing with settings fixed it.

1. Check that your system settings are correct (Settings -> Text Entry).
2. Make sure also that shortcut is not taken in `Keyboard Shortcuts` and that no key associated with `Next input method`. Try to remove everything from `Input Methods` settings.
3. Go to keyboard settings, and change layout configurations.
4. Try to clean/reset mapping settings: [How do I clear xmodmap settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29603/how-do-i-clear-xmodmap-settings)

If it still doesn't work try:

4. Check that the plugin `xfce4-xkb-plugin` is installed (just run `sudo apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin`)
5. try to map manually `sudo setxkbmap -optiongrp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle us,ru`

Comment: Installing xfce4-xkb-plugin makes the Alt-Shift "next input method" from "Keyboard Layouts / iBus Preferences" shortcut work. But If I use the iBus language icon widget on my toolbar, it somehow cancels Alt-Shift and it will no longer work until the next restart. It's good enough a workaround for me, though, because I prefer the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the indicator and click preferences.
2. Select the advanced tab.
3. Unselect "Use system keyboard layout".

[image: Screenshot]